# Why is my 5GHz the same speed as my 2.4GHz?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have two computers laptop and a desktop, the thing is both computers support a 5Ghz band.

When looking into desktop's properties it says "network band: 2.4Ghz" although it supports 5Ghz. I changed its settings through device manager but it keeps showing 2.4Ghz band, I don't what to change or what to do because as I told you before my laptop is running at 5Ghz speed but my desktop although it supports 5Ghz it's not running at such speed both computers are near my router.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Desktop:
[image]

Laptop:
[image]

Comment: I changed its settings through device manager but it keeps showing 2.4Ghz band,     ....  I don't do that. Use Windows Settings or the Wireless Icon to make sure network cards are on the correct band. I have a machine here on 5G and one on 2.4G with a defective card (waiting for the new one) . Most definite difference in speed.

Comment: The two screenshots clearly indicate they are NOT the same speed. The laptop is nearly twice as fast as the desktop. Can you provide specifics on the hardware by editing your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: If you believe both laptop & pc support 5GHz, then just turn 2.4GHz off in the wifi router and see how far you get.

Comment: Hey, thanks all of you for your answers.

I do know that both my laptop and desktop support 5Ghz because not a long time ago I was able to speed test my desktop and it gave me 200Mbps.....

Now, as you could notice my desktop is not giving the full support and it's only supporting 2.4 although I already turned off 2.4Ghz band from my router.